# Shell script to get difference between previous commit and current commit in azure DevOps

Tags: bash, git, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We wanted to implement incremental deployment, for which I need to find difference between current commit and previous commit. I need to write a diff command like we have for git.

Could you please let me know how to get difference between to commits in Azure DevOps.

My current Shell script not working:

[image]

The output is:

[image: Output]

Comment: Why not use the git diff command? it should works.

Comment: I wanted to use it in azure devops where we can create a shell script task. Git diff is not returning any result even azure devops uses git for repository. I am kind of stuck here.

Comment: Which results `git diff` returns? can you share what did you try and the log?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk  it returns nothing.

#!/bin/bash

metaItems="$(git diff)"

echo "metaitems......"
echo "$metaItems"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get results because you don't give the arguments to the command, you need to add the compare commits, for example:

```
git diff 34b34 1bbh4
```

And in your script:

```
metaItems="$(git diff 34b34 1bbh4)"
```

Now you can print the variable and you will see the differences between the commits.

Comment: Thank you very much. git diff was returning result without passing any argument at on my local repository in vs code, that is a reason I was using that command. Now all is good.